# Adding functionality to an existing C API

Tags: c, api, thread-safety

I have a legacy C API that I need to add functionality to.  Specifically I need to make some of this API's calls thread-safe, because a call like this:

```
A_DoFoo(HandleA a)
```

Uses an object shared by all handles of type A.

My first thought is to add a function to the API that looks like this:

```
A_DoFooEx(HandleA a, HandleB b)
```

Is this a normal approach?

(I only used the Ex suffix because of years of exposure to the Win32 SDK.  Does it make more sense to give a more descriptive name to the function?)

Comment: why do you need to change the interface? Why not use internal locking?

Comment: A_DooFoo locks properly around the shared object of type B, but it cannot actually exploit parallelism because there is only one shared object.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Adding another function under a new name is the standard (and in fact just about the only) way to deal with this problem in straight C (in C++ you could add a new overload and keep the old name).  I'm not a big fan of the `Ex` suffix, because it doesn't tell you what the difference between the old and new APIs is.  On the other hand, don't saddle people with something long and heinous like `A_DoFoo_ThreadSafe`, that hurts readability.

In this case, I'd try to think of a name that indicates what the requirements on `HandleB` are.  If you tell us what this API actually does, we can maybe make more specific suggestions.

Comment: This is for image processing.  A_DoFoo(A) is A_GenerateImage(A, &image).  Under the hood it's calling ImageGenerator::GenerateImage(A) on a ImageGenerator shared across all instances of A. (It's actually worse than this, as there's a second type of shared object).  It would make sense to have ImageGenerator_GenerateImage(A) but this goes against the existing API's convention of A_GenerateImage.  Maybe I should just force any thread-safe use to use this different convention.

Comment: First things that come to mind are `A_GenerateImageWithGenerator` or the less explicit, but kinda catchy IMO, `A_GenerateImageG`.

Answer (score 0):

I prefer writing wrapper for thread safe code. So I can embedded any thread un safe code and make it thread safe use wrapper.

You should always use a proper naming format. 
it will help  you easily maintain your code and make it more readable.

Comment: I can't remove any existing signatures and I can't change any existing behavior.

Comment: I am not telling you to remove any other existing behavior. Just wrap it around your thread safe functions.